# Why Lua doesn't have real global variables?

Tags: lua

Lua doesn't really have global variables, it uses table to implement global variables. All global variables are stored in the `_G` table.

> This is mentioned in Section 22.3 of the book "Programming in Lua", available on the official [lua website](http://www.lua.org/pil/):
> Lua doesn't even have global variables at all. Lua goes to great lengths to give programmers the illusion of global variables, and to maintain the illusion of global variables, Lua maintains a table internally that serves as the global environment.

I don't know why Lua does this, I've tried to find an answer, but I've only found vague statements like: global variables are variables that are visible throughout the entire program, but Lua is designed to be an embeddable language that is called by the host program, and in order to solve this dilemma, Lua uses table emulation to implement global variables.

> This is expressed in chapter 22 (Environment) of the "Programming in Lua".

I'd like to know: what does "this dilemma" mean? What are the intractable problems with "real global variables" and "being an embeddable language"? So much so that Lua doesn't design real global variables.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why there is so much unsupport?

Comment: What do you call "real" global variables?

Comment: `Lua is designed to be an embeddable language that is called by the host program, and in order to solve this dilemma, Lua uses table emulation to implement global variables.` -- I read that as "Lua stores its global variables in a table to distinguish its own variables from the variables of the host environment."  In this way, Lua doesn't have to provide an "environment within an environment;" it can just emulate variables using a table.

Comment: "*As far as I know, lua doesn't really have global variables*" -- That Lua provides storage for global variables in a (global) table does not make them any less global, or any less variables.  Being global is about the visibility of the variable's identifier.  That a variable's value might *also* be accessible by another means is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c`, `c++`, and `unity game engine`?

Comment: Storing values in a "table" is nothing new.  Hashmaps and dictionaries have been a thing for decades.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Because Lua is often used for game development

Comment: @adabsurdum I really didn't realise so many people didn't know this, I've added. It's horrible and I don't know why this issue was closed just after it was raised.

Comment: Any interpreted language that provides for user-defined variables needs to provide storage for them in a table or a similar data structure.  The only interesting thing here -- and not unique to Lua -- is that the language provides for that table to itself be accessed and manipulated via the language's normal functions and operators.

Comment: @无数_wushu -- _"I don't know why so many people don't realise that lua doesn't actually have global variables...."_ The Lua reference manual calls them "global variables", and never says that they aren't real global variables. _PIL_ briefly suggests that they aren't "real" global variables, but isn't entirely clear about what "real" means in this context. The reference manual does say that `_ENV` is an _external local variable_. This mechanism provides flexibility not usually associated with global variables, and I think that is what the author was getting at, but you would have to ask them.

Comment: One thing that hasn't been mentioned yet: A variable is just a free name (not a keyword or a dot field), and Lua's globals definitely fulfill that criteria, so they are real variables. The fact that they're stored in a table is merely an implementation. You still haven't explained the core issue of your question. What can you do with globals in other languages that you can't do with Lua's globals?

Comment: I'd actually say that the way Lua stores globals in a table that's accessible to the user is even more flexible than some other languages. Also it makes perfect sense from the design, every local environment is also a table which builds a chain up to the global table.

Answer (score 7):

> Why Lua doesn't have real global variables?

It does have global variables, variables which are visible throughout the interpreter environment.

> All global variables are stored in the _G table

The fact that Lua provides a way to access its symbol table doesn't affect the scope of variables. It's `_ENV`, not `_G`, though.

Quoting [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html),

> *An access to a global variable `x` is equivalent to `_ENV.x`.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it wasn't the core reason I wanted to know.
I don't know why so many people don't realise that lua doesn't actually have global variables, probably because I didn't provide evidence of it in the first place, so the issue was quickly closed, which was a terrible experience.